# After upgrade to android lollipop Moto G 1st Gen getting slow and lagging

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, motorola-moto-g

My Moto G 1st Gen mobile is getting lag and slow after upgrade to android lollipop.
Please help me to get it fix.Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

No need to reset the phone.Clearing cache partition should do the job.
[How to clear cache partition on Moto G](http://allaboutmotog.com/how-to-clear-cache-partition-on-moto-g-and-moto-x-after-android-lollipop-update/)

Comment: I already did and did not help for me. I guess a factory reset is the only option left.

Comment: I don't think that factory reset might help if clearing cache didn't help. Anyway no harm in trying. But be sure yo backup your data before doing so.

Answer (score 1):

The official guide to Moto G Clear Cache process is [here](https://motorola-global-portal.custhelp.com/app/answers/prod_answer_detail/a_id/97335/p/30%2C6720%2C9050/reg/2371020/kw/clear%20cache).

But the only combination that worked to access the "wipe cache partition" menu was:
[Try to press and hold Power Button for at least two seconds and then without releasing the Power Button press Vol. Up key]

Comment: The instructions are outdated for Lollipop. It's now the opposite. On the Android in distress icon, you'll want to press the Power button a few seconds, then tap on Volume Up. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I did the below method and it worked fine for me,

- Do a backup of your phone
- Do a factory reset.
- Restore your phone

It should be fast now.

Comment: Does it really speed things up? I just though the phone couldn't really hand OS 5.0.